# Cannot pass props to component through connect()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am using React / Redux with TypeScript transpilation. I want my navigation menu to read from state and to maintain its own mini-state.

NavMenu.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavLink, Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from '../store';
import * as NavigationStore from '../store/Navigation';

type NavigationProps =
  NavigationStore.NavigationState
  & typeof NavigationStore.actionCreators;

class NavMenu extends React.Component<NavigationProps, {}> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <nav className='main-nav'>
        <ul className={`nav-standard`}>
            <li>
                <NavLink exact to={'/'} activeClassName='active'>
                    Home
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NavLink to={'/learn'} activeClassName='active'>
                    Learn
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NavLink to={'/blog'} activeClassName='active'>
                    Blog
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div className='nav-small'>
          <button type='button' className='navbar-toggle' onClick={() => { this.props.toggle() } }>
              <span className='screen-reader-content'>Toggle Navigation</span>
              <i className='fa fa-bars'></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.navigation,
    NavigationStore.actionCreators
)(NavMenu) as typeof NavMenu;
```

Here is how I am trying to render the navbar, Layout.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import NavMenu from './NavMenu';

export class Layout extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  public render() {
    return <div>
      <NavMenu />
      { this.props.children }
    </div>;
  }
}
```

I'm getting a typescript transpilation error:

`TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<NavMenu> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & R...'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<NavigationProps>'.
    Property 'expanded' is missing in type '{}'.`

Isn't this the purpose of the connect() function? To automatically map state and actions to a component? This is normally the error I get when not passing props down to a component (without using connect()).

**EDIT**
It does work when I exhaustively pass down all the properties expected for a `NavigationProps` type:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import NavMenu from './NavMenu';

export class Layout extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  public render() {
    return <div>
      <NavMenu expanded={false} expand={Navigation.actionCreators.expand} constrict={Navigation.actionCreators.constrict} toggle={Navigation.actionCreators.toggle} />
      { this.props.children }
    </div>;
  }
}
```

`Navigation.ts` for posterity (new import):

```
import { Action, Reducer } from 'redux';

export interface NavigationState {
  expanded: boolean;
};

interface ExpandNavigationAction { type: 'EXPAND_NAVIGATION' }
interface ConstrictNavigationAction { type: 'CONSTRICT_NAVIGATION' }
interface ToggleNavigationAction { type: 'TOGGLE_NAVIGATION' }

type KnownAction = ExpandNavigationAction
  | ConstrictNavigationAction
  | ToggleNavigationAction;

export const actionCreators = {
  expand: () => <ExpandNavigationAction>{ type: 'EXPAND_NAVIGATION' },
  constrict: () => <ConstrictNavigationAction>{ type: 'CONSTRICT_NAVIGATION' 
},
  toggle: () => <ToggleNavigationAction>{ type: 'TOGGLE_NAVIGATION' }
};

export const reducer: Reducer<NavigationState> = (state: NavigationState, 
action: KnownAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'EXPAND_NAVIGATION':
      return { expanded: true };
    case 'CONSTRICT_NAVIGATION':
        return { expanded: false };
    case 'TOGGLE_NAVIGATION':
        return { expanded: !state.expanded };
    default:
        const exhaustiveCheck: never = action;
  }
  return state || { expanded: false };
}
```

Even though this transpiles successfully, my goal when doing this was to avoid writing out such verbose markup. I was under the impression the whole point of the connect() method was to simply and easily pass the correct properties from state down to the child component via mapper methods.

Comment: Does your redacted code set the `expanded` state property somewhere? It looks like you specified the empty object for `state` type but later set `state.expanded`.

Comment: I redacted that code only for brevity, I have added it to the original post. No references to state.expanded, but I imagine this would start transpiling again if I manually passed down every property to the <NavMenu /> component. I will do so and update you with an edit to the post.

Comment: Updated question again, it does indeed work if I pass down all the types, but the goal of using the connect() method was to avoid having to be so verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't cast the result of `connect()` to `typeof NavMenu`. When you do that you're telling TS that the component expects a `NavigationProps` object to be passed in as a property. So it makes sense that you get an error when you don't pass in any properties.

The wrapped component created by `connect()` has no required properties.

Comment: Wow, it really was just that simple! Useful for anybody who is trying to expand the .NET Core 2.0 boilerplate in VS2017, I just continued the pattern used previously.